# Double Application on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, apk

I want ti install **same app twice without replacing the each Other**.
something like :I Want play a game from the start **without losing previous game saved data**.so, Is there a way i can install **same apk** twice without replacing the previous one. is it possible??

Will changing the apk package name & changing default installed Directory of app work?,but i think it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can I do that before **BY**:

You must have a different package name (make sure the package name in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file is different), there is no other way. I had two different versions of the same product (free & paid) and used: `com.package.paid` & `com.package.free`.

This means that nothing is shared between the two apps (DB included).

You can also use ANT scripts to build both apps from the same code base, I just changed it manually every time I needed to build a version. Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, android only allow one version of an app exists. Do an upgrade or downgrade installation, or find another device to install the same app.